# Add looping scroll to my carousel in Prototype-UI

Tags: javascript, user-interface, prototypejs

I have a carousel that scrolls fine but when it comes to the end of the content (`<li>.</li>`) it just stops. I would like it to start again from the beginning.

Here is my code that I have hobbled together as not to good with JavaScript etc..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function startscroll() {
    x = window.setInterval(function scroll() {
        hCarousel.scrollTo(hCarousel.currentIndex() + 3);
    },3000);
}

function stopscroll() {
    window.clearInterval(x);
}

function runTest() {
    hCarousel = new UI.Carousel("horizontal_carousel", {direction: "horizontal"});
    startscroll();
    $('horizontal_carousel').observe('mouseover', stopscroll);
    $('horizontal_carousel').observe('mouseout', startscroll);
}

Event.observe(window, "load", runTest);

</script>
```

Thanks for any help
Dave.

Answer (score 2):

change this

`$('horizontal_carousel').observe('mouseover', stopscroll);
    $('horizontal_carousel').observe('mouseout', startscroll);`

to

```
  $('horizontal_carousel').onmouseover = function(){
stopscroll();
}
        $('horizontal_carousel').onmouseout = function(){
startscroll();
}`
```